# consecutive punctuations in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: punctuation

> No, perhaps it was her who did it.
>
> No, perhaps, it was her who did it.

I think the second is the conventional way, but it also looks weird to me for some reason. Is the first correct? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Perhaps is almost never separated with a comma. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213965/do-you-use-a-comma-after-perhaps-to-begin-a-sentence

Comment: Same with rather?

Comment: No, perhaps it was SHE who did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle distinction in meaning between those two sentences. "No, perhaps it was her who did it" implies that a prior statement or hypothesis is being rejected, for the alternative possibility of "her" doing "it." On the other hand, "No, perhaps, it was her who did it" makes the sentence portray kind of a pondering tone that develops more certainty as it goes on, since perhaps isn't as strongly linked to "it was her who did it."

The second version also looks much more awkward.